# how to multiply a variable with every value of an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var numbers = [1, 5, 10, 15];
var doubles = numbers.map(function(x) {
  return x * 2;
  //doubles is now [2, 10, 20, 30]
```

I am following this above example, This is working for a constant 2, how can I mulitply the elements with variable `this.price`,

```
var numbers = [1, 5, 10, 15];
var doubles = numbers.map(function(x) {
   return x * this.price;
```

How can I make this works? `this.price` is a public variable.

Comment: The problem is because this refers to your function. Read about closures and javascript scope.

Comment: you would have to bind price to use it in this scope

Comment: Bro simply use the loop for,foreach or while.

var numbers = [1, 5, 10, 15];

for (index = 0; index < numbers .length; ++index) {
//your multiplication code goes here
}

Comment: You can use arrow functions.. `var doubles = numbers.map(x => x * this.price);`

Comment: @Nikola That is some truly terrible advice.

Comment: Sorry 'this' is window object , He need only to define like price = 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doubles = numbers.map(function(x) {
   return x * this.price; // "this" refers to the function it's inside
})
```

You can pass the external context inside the function using the ES6 fat arrow :

```
let doubles = numbers.map( x => x * this.price ) // "this" now refers to the parent's scope
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numbers = [1, 5, 10, 15];

var doubles = numbers.map(x => x * 5);

console.log(doubles);
```

Answer (score -3):

simply use the loop for,foreach or while.

```
var numbers = [1, 5, 10, 15];
for (index = 0; index < numbers .length; ++index) {
    //your multiplication code goes here
}
```